# Sobolev spaces embedding and inclusion relationships between $H^k$, $W_\infty^k$, and $C$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am learning the Sobolev embedding theorem through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality, but it seems too complicated to me. Actually, as a beginner I don't need so many advanced discussions. Please let me just ask THREE elementary questions in the following simplified setting:

Let $W_p^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Sobolev space of real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n, ~ n=2,3$ (yes we only consider 2-d or 3-d), whose first $k$th weak derivatives are measurable functions in $L_p$.

1. Do we have the inclusion $H^k(\mathbb{R}^n) := W_2^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset W_\infty^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $k \ge 0$ AND $n=2,3$?
   If not, in which situation does it hold (for what $k$ and what $n$)?
2. Do we have the inclusion $H^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $k \ge 0$ AND $n=2,3$?
   If not, in which situation does it hold (for what $k$ and what $n$)?
3. Do we have the inclusion $W_\infty^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $k \ge 0$ AND $n=2,3$?
   If not, in which situation does it hold (for what $k$ and what $n$)?

I would appreciate it if you could please just answer the above questions with very simple explanations.

Comment: Short answer: 1. No, for any $k$ and $n$ this fails. 2. It fails if $k\leq 1$, for your values of $n$. 3. Obviously fails if $k=0$, and is true if $k\geq 1$ (independent of $n$).

Comment: Thank you @Jose27 Could you further explain for 1. why $H^k \subset W_\infty^k$ is false?

Comment: The issue there is the domain $\mathbb{R}^n$, since $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\not\subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (so the inclusion fails for $k=0$, but similar arguments will give you that if fails for any $k>0$ as well). If instead your domain was a *bounded* (or at least finite measure) open set, then the inclusion is true and it follows from Hölder's inequality.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you very much for your clear answer! I am still considering if $W_\infty^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ holds for any $k \ge 1$, how about $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset W_\infty^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$?